# How to put wmv videos into my iPad 2 on Mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, wmv

Recently i made my own videos with Windows Movie Maker and output the vidoes as .wmv format on my computer, now i want to put it onto my iPad 2, so that i can easily share with my friend and easily send email for my parents.How do i do this?

My iPad 2 runs iOS 5.O and  Mac runs Apple OS X Lion 10.7.

Comment: Wrong site, this is Stack Overflow

Comment: Use AirPlay or OPlayer HD on the iPad to play WMV or convert to mp4 using Handbrake.

Answer (score 3):

Apple only supports a handful of video formats on the i-devices. [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), in addition to being a great ripper, converts files, and has a preset for the iPad2 (and most other iWassnames)- i believe it'll convert it to m4v or some flavour of xvid which you can upload to your iPad with iTunes.

For sharing, if possible leave it as WMV - WMV is already lossy, and reconversion will probably make it worse.

Comment: Handbrake is awesome and super-easy to use.  The iPad presets work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use WMV files on iPad. You can, however, convert them to 3gp or m4v format, using a utility like the [Miro Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/).